# iPhone GUI objects migrating position between normal and retina display

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, user-interface, uiviewcontroller, retina-display

I am developing and app for iPhone which uses graphics for retina and non-retina displays.
Every UIViewController displays both the status bar and the navigation bar.
The views' simulated metrics values are set correctly for the above options.

The issue I am facing is that the buttons are migrating about 30 pixels when the app runs on iPhone 4. The resize settings of all the GUI objects are set to default.

Could you help me with this issue?

Thank you,
Andrei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the @2x version of the images exactly twice the resolution of the non-retina versions?

Different sizes can cause the images to change places between displays.

Can you check the value of the frames of buttons both on 3GS and iPhone 4 and see if they are the same?